# Ajax Call Returning Empty

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

i have a form as follows:

```
<div class="any_reg">

            <div class="mail_area">
                <form name="any_reg" id="any_reg" method="POST" action="" class="mail_area">
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" id="mail" placeholder="Enter Your Email"></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $auction ?>">
                <td><input type="submit" name="submitmail" id="submitmail" value="Submit"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

i have an ajax call as follows:
i have given the url as `$ajaxUrl= $dir."/watchemailajax.php";`

```
  if(tre == true){
            $.ajax({url: '<?php echo $ajaxUrl; ?>',method:'POST',
                    data:$('#any_reg').serialize()
                    ,success: function(result){
                        alert(result);
                        if (result== "Success"){

                            alert("SUCCESS");   
                        }else
                        {
                            alert("Failed");
                        }
```

Which Goes to a page with the following code:

```
 <?php
    if (strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],WPA_PLUGIN_NAME) && isset($_GET['submitmail'])){
    check_ajax_referer( "WPA-nonce" );

      $auction_id = $_POST['auction_id'];
      $watch_email = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
      $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_wpa_watchlist";

      $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (auction_id, watch_email) VALUES (".$auction_id.", '".$watch_email."' );";
      $result = $wpdb->query($sql);

      if ($result){
        echo "Success";
          // _e("You will be notified of any changes to this auction",'wpauctions');
      }
      else {
        echo "Failed";
      }
    }
```

The call is returning empty data and nothing else. I am kinda newbie when it comes to Ajax and anything related to it. please help me. Wht is my mistake

Comment: What status code does the HTTP call return? It could be that you are getting an unrecoverable 500 error because of an error in your script.

Comment: While on other side watchemailajax.php check this $auction_id = $_POST['auction_id']; and do print and make exit and check is it returning data or not?

Comment: SQL injection alert

Comment: Add a else clause to the first if statement and see if that returns anything. It might be that conditions for that first if statement are not met thus not executing its contents

Comment: @JesseSchokker yes am getting a 500 internal server error

Comment: Add this to your script in order to turn on full error logging. From what I can see there are no obvious syntax errors: ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @JesseSchokker You are right the code is not getting into the loop since its failing the initial conditions.

Comment: Do you want me to post this as an answer, so this question can get an accepted answer?

Comment: Sure and go ahead !

Comment: Thank you for accepting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be failing to meet the requirements for this if statement `if (strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],WPA_PLUGIN_NAME) && isset($_GET['submitmail'])){` thus causing it to skip execution of the script. Add an else statement to the first if statement and add a message so you can see when it fails like so:

```
    if (strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],WPA_PLUGIN_NAME) && isset($_GET['submitmail'])){
        check_ajax_referer( "WPA-nonce" );

          $auction_id = $_POST['auction_id'];
          $watch_email = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
          $tablename = $wpdb->prefix . "wp_wpa_watchlist";

          $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tablename." (auction_id, watch_email) VALUES (".$auction_id.", '".$watch_email."' );";
          $result = $wpdb->query($sql);

          if ($result){
            echo "Success";
              // _e("You will be notified of any changes to this auction",'wpauctions');
          }
          else {
            echo "Failed";
          }
        }
       else {

           echo "Failed if statement";

       }
```

Comment: but i still cant figure it out whts causing the problem so tht its not entering the loop
i rewrote this to if (strstr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],WPA_PLUGIN_NAME) && isset($_GET['submitmail'])) to

if(isset($_GET['submitmail'])) and still the problem exists

Comment: Try putting those values in a var_dump and see what the output is. It allows you to accurately read the variable's contents.

Comment: i did it and it returns an empty array, neither the given email nor the id is getting displayed

Comment: Make sure that data is in this element "$('#any_reg').serialize()", as that is what you are sending the PHP script.

Comment: Yes u are rite its not passing any values, when i tried to alert it, its nthng but empty

Comment: Can Anybody Help ? ?  ? ?

Comment: Well, I can't really help because I don't know what information you are trying to serialize in that div.

Comment: i have added my html form code also, its just a simple email submit form

Comment: Can you add "console.log($('#any_reg').serialize());" to your code, so I can read the output of it. Might tell us why it is not sending the correct values.

Comment: Wp_Auction Error: Error Undefined , this is what am getting\

Comment: Can Yu tell me how to pass the data via ajax without serializing

Comment: data: {  email: $("#email").val() } to get the email value, pt this in the ajax code.

Comment: after a thorough go through , i have found that ma values are getting passed. Now ma issue is $wpdb when var dumped is returning null.
for tht i included global $wpdb but still its returning null.

Comment: I am not familiar with that plugin or whatever it may be, so I can't really help you there.

Comment: Please, make sure you provide safe code in your answer by preventing SQL injection (use prepared statements or at least clean the POST variables)